# Traveling to Australia with an expired Australian passport

Tags: customs-and-immigration, australian-citizens

I am traveling to Australia and I am a dual citizen (Maltese and Australian). As my Australian passport is expired, can I travel to Australia with my Maltese passport? What should I show the immigration in Australia on my arrival to show them that I am Australian?

Answer (score 4):

> [What documents do Australian citizens need to return to
>   Australia?](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/lega/lega/form/immi-faqs/i-am-an-australian-citizen-what-documents-do-i-need-to-come-back-into-australia)
>
> If you are an Australian citizen, you:
>
> ```
> do not need a visa to enter Australia
> must have a valid Australian passport or other acceptable travel document
> will need a completed and signed Incoming Passenger Card.
> ```
>
> If you are an Australian citizen and you hold dual or multiple
>   nationalities, you should use your Australian passport to enter or
>   leave Australia, even if you use a foreign passport when you are
>   outside Australia. The only exception is if you have been issued with
>   an Australian Declaratory Visa.

It would be best to contact the Australian consulate to get your passport renewed, or to obtain a travel document if you need to travel more quickly than they can process the renewal. This is backed up by Timatic, the database used by airlines for immigration information, which says:

> - Dual nationals of Australia must enter and depart using their Australian passport.

While some countries will allow you to travel home on an expired passport, Australia is not one of them:

> - Passports and other documents accepted for entry must be
>     valid on arrival.

Comment: Note that technically you cannot be refused entry to Australia once you get in front of an Australian immigration agent with an expired passport. Only issue is getting to Australian soil in the first place.